# For what 'upgrade wave' is "Get Windows 10" application currently waiting?

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-10-upgrade

Automatically downloaded Windows 10 installer sits in

`C:\$Windows.~BT`

and has size of **3,928,296,443 bytes**.

But it is almost 24 hours since the download activity stopped and the upgrade assistant still states *We'll let you known when ready.*

**Isn't that 3.9 GB the final size of the package? Are there any extra downloads to come?** Or is the process stuck? Should I continue waiting or should I do something?

Additional details:

- Reservation is valid.
- All available updates were applied using Windows Update.
- Upgrade compatibility screen looks OK (0 errors reported, all icons are green check-marks).
- Directory `C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources` takes most of the above volume and
  Directory `C:\$Windows.~BT\NewOS` is empty.

Comment: You don't have to create installation media, the tool can do an in-place upgrade, and does exactly what the Windows Update method does.  I remove my comments as you requested, despite being accused of being hostile, when I wasn't being hostile.  I actually was attempting to help you, sharing some information I know, I cannot fathom how that is being hostile.  Microsoft has shared **zero** information on how they are rolling out the update, just that there are waves, and everyone will eventually be upgraded.

Comment: I have over **285** answers.  I know what makes a good answer.  My comment isn't an answer to this question, it is helpful and that command should work, my problem was caused because of a `Acronis True Image` driver conflict.

Comment: I found this [article](http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-says-it-could-be-weeks-before-you-get-your-windows-10-upgrade-notification) in the last 30 minutes.  If you are not being prompted to actually perform the upgrade then you don't have the entire download.

Comment: @Ramhound - great information, setting my expectations properly :)   I don't mind if you could later transfer this into an answer. I'll gladly accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As [@Ramhound said](https://superuser.com/questions/948722/for-what-upgrade-wave-is-get-windows-10-application-currently-waiting/950354#comment1293275_948722), the 4 GB of downloaded files was only one part. And it was just needed to wait. Later, when installation begun, another 4 GB download has launched. (Or was it a redownload?)
2. The installation wave kept failing, multiple failures were seen in Windows Update history.
3. Manual launch attempt using `wuauclt.exe /updatenow` was failing with **error 80240020**. Meaning of the error: the installer wants to pop-up a window for interaction with user and such an action is not allowed when running through Windows auto-updater. (In this case, it was window for acceptance of the license agreement.)
4. [Solution at answers.microsoft.com helped.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-windows_install/windows-update-installation-failure-80240020/d695e827-9774-4e10-8972-df8d51a7bb51?auth=1)
   Create/Set `DWORD` registy value `AllowOSUpgrade` = `1` in key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\WindowsUpdate\OSUpgrade`, close control panels and re-check for updates (from Windows Update control panel). Interactive installer now pops-up and the rest is fine.